# problem in contraction mapping

Tags: analysis

give an example of a function $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ such that $\forall x,y \in \Bbb R$,$|f(x)-f(y)|\lt|x-y|$ but there is no $x \in\Bbb R$ such that $f(x)=x$

Comment: Something simple like $x+1$ ? (By the way, if you really meant $<$, notice that it is not possible : e.g. with $x = y$)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: What must happen if f is continuous?